# difference between Theme.AppCompat, @style/Theme.AppCompat, and @android:style/Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat

what's the difference between:

- Theme.AppCompat
- @style/Theme.AppCompat
- @android:style/Theme.AppCompat

and in which case should we use one vs the other?

Also, does it make a difference if we write

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

instead of

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

Comment: The third one is not possible, as `@android:style/` refers to a style resource that is part of the Android framework, not from a library. AFAIK, the other two are equivalent.

Comment: thanks, good to know these two are equivalent. Could you point me to a good documentation/tutorial on the subject?